# State variables not getting rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to Reactjs and trying to do some simple stuff. In the below code snippet I have declared two state variable `counter` and `setCounter` to `9` but when I am rendering both of them in the UI `{setCounter}` is not getting rendered whereas I am able to see `9` in the UI which is the `{counter}`

```
import * as React from 'react';
const {useState} = React;
export default function App()
{
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(9); // Declaring State variables 
  return (
    <>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <p>{setCounter}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: setCounter is a function

Comment: @lissettdm how is it a function? isn't that an array of two variables?

Comment: See, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: thanks... will go through it

Comment: your wrapping tags for the HTML are empty, fix that with a `<div>` at least

Comment: @AGE That is a short syntax for React Fragment
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Nice to learn something new, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setCounter is a function. Let me explain how this works. I drafted up a function based on the example you provided.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(9); // Declaring State variables 

  const addOne = () => {
    if (counter === 9) {
      setCounter(counter + 1)
    };
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => { addOne() }}></button>
      <p>{counter}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

I created a function where I take the 9 that you assigned and set the counter to that value, and increment by one. Then in the return, I created a button. When clicked, the button will call the addOne function and setCounter to increment by one. I hope this illustrates the difference here and why you won't be able to simply render setCounter.

Comment: very nice explaination. but what is the difference between `function addOne() {
    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }` and `const addOne = () => {
      setCounter(counter + 1)
  }` when they are doing the same job. `Which one is more preferable?`

Comment: No problem - I illustrated that way to be more explicit. You can certainly just do it as you suggested. I didn't include a condition in this one to save some space. You can click the button and it will keep incrementing the counter. But I hope it illustrates the utility the same way as the previous example.

`import React, {useState} from 'react';
export default function App()
{
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(9); // Declaring State variables 

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => {setCounter(counter + 1)}}></button>
      <p>{counter}</p>
    </>
  )
}`

Answer (score 1):

Hey friend I recommend you to see the React documentation, since it is just starting, check it out on the subject of states.
As for what you are doing, the first thing setCounter is not a variable, it's a function that changes the value to the variable counter, counter is a variable that you can call in any part of your component or you can even send through the props to other components. Hopefully you have served this little help, but it is never too late to start with the time you will dominate friend. Thank you very much.

Documentation link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html